# @State variable causing app to crash when VC is being destroyed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am have a SwiftUi hosted in UIHostingController, code here:

```
class GenericViewController<Content>: UIHostingController<Content> where Content: View {
override init(rootView: Content) {
    super.init(rootView: rootView)
}

@MainActor @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

And the simple SwiftUI here:

```
struct TestView: View {
@State private var isTimeout: Bool = false
private func onload() {
    isTimeout = false
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 5){
        isTimeout = true
    }
}

private func toIntroScreen() {
    // caused this VC to destroy
    WindowManager.shared().setRootWindow(type: .Intro)
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if !isTimeout {
            Text("Waiting")
        } else {
            Button("Go Back") {
                self.toIntroScreen()
            }
        }
    }.onAppear(perform: onload)
}
```

This screen is the 2nd screen so when user clicks "Go Back", this SwiftUI will be destroyed going back to the 1st screen. When I go this, the app will crash with the following call stack:

Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x0000000000000000 in 0x00000000 ()
#1  0x0000000105fbb324 in _swift_release_dealloc ()
#2  0x00000001026354e4 in destroy for TestView ()
#3  0x000000010bfac77c in @objc _UIHostingView.__ivar_destroyer ()
#4  0x0000000102f7be30 in object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) ()
#5  0x0000000102f8f620 in objc_destructInstance ()
#6  0x0000000102f95ea0 in _objc_rootDealloc ()

When i remove @State var from this, go back will go back to the previous screen without issue so I know having the @State caused this to crash but I don't understand why. I'm running iOS13 SDK on Simulator.

I wonder if someone ran into this issue before?

Comment: It would help to have a [mre]. What happens if you use `[weak self]` in your `DispatchQueue` call?

Comment: Using weak self might work around the crash, but I believe it won't solve the main problem: The value won't be accessible anyway.

Comment: SwiftUI uses struct. Trying to use weak or unowned on a non-class type isn't allowed in Swift.